# Check on output/logs of cell in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a cell in Jupyter Notebook that takes a long time to run, and I would like to check on the output to make sure it's actually making progress and not stuck. Is there a way to peek at the output of the cell before it's complete? If it makes a difference, this cell is running a bash subprocess.

Comment: not yet, but I'll give it a try! I was hoping for a solution that would not require me to restart this cell that has been running for more than 24 hours...